# Custom Lubuntu iso errors

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, live-cd, bios, custom-distributions

I am working on a project for which I need to make a specific and lightweight linux distribution. I have made a custom LiveCD ISO based on Lubuntu 12.04 for my project, and when I try running it in Virtualbox 4.2.6 it starts all right and gives the boot options menu:

[image]

However, when I check the disk for defects, it says there is one:

[image]
[image]

**I need to know exactly which file the problem is in.** It also will not start the livecd system or installer, supposedly for some sort of BIOS problem:

[image]

Please note: I have a deadline on this project.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with VirtualBox not necessarily a problem with your .ISO. Try booting from the .ISO in a local machine.